# Caffe2/detectron infer_simple does not detect any objects

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, caffe2

I have installed Caffe2 (using Anaconda package for python 2.7) and Detectron in an Ubuntu 18.04 system. Both installations were successful without errors and I have verified them.

However, on running the given detectron example infer_simple with the command given [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md),

```
python2 tools/infer_simple.py \
--cfg configs/12_2017_baselines/e2e_mask_rcnn_R-101-FPN_2x.yaml \
--output-dir /tmp/detectron-visualizations \
--image-ext jpg \
--wts https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/detectron/35861858/12_2017_baselines/e2e_mask_rcnn_R-101-FPN_2x.yaml.02_32_51.SgT4y1cO/output/train/coco_2014_train:coco_2014_valminusminival/generalized_rcnn/model_final.pkl \
demo
```

the script is executed without outputting the expected pdf images. The terminal output and nvidia-smi shows that inference is being carried out.

[image: terminal output]

On using the argument `--output always` which outputs pdf images even when there aren't any detections I am able to produce the output pdfs (however indicating no detection boxes).

I have tried reducing the threshold value for detections with no luck.

Why is detectron inference not detecting (and outputting) any objects?